# How to format a list reference like 12a,b,c?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Suppose I have a reference to a website from a manufacturer with 1000000 webpages. In my bibliography I would need something like

```
12. Manufacturer Name, address
    a) webpage reference
    b) webpage reference
    c) webpage reference
```

How can I then say for this formula see [11] for the next see [12a], for another one see [12b] and so on?

Mico: The point is that on each webpage is a formula., e.g. https://functions.wolfram.com/06.19.17.0008.01
If I want to send the reader to that webpage, the link is needed because the reader will never find it if that person does not understand the structure of the 100000 other formulas and how they are organized. Next I want the reader to look up https://functions.wolfram.com/06.18.02.0001.01 And so on, all on the same website, but a different needle in the haystack.

\documentclass[10pt,english]{article}

I use \bibliographystyle{myvancouver}, an edited version of the vancouver style, JabRef and TexShop

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of curiosity: What's the point you're looking to make by mentioning that the 3 webpages you wish to list and cross-reference come from a list of 1,000,000 -- you're sure it's not 1,000,002 or 1,000,005? :-) -- webpages?

Comment: Please also tell us more about your document setup. With document class do you employ, and which bibliography style do you use? Do you use a citation management package?

Comment: @Mico Edited text. Does that help?

Comment: If I understand your posting correctly, you're looking to create a novel, two-tier bibliographic entry type in order to solve an issue which (a) 99.99% of all readers of your paper couldn't care less about and (b) would probably not improve the readability of your document. (The 2 points are obviously not independent.) IMNSHO, if the 3 formulas are sufficiently important in their own right, your readers will be better off if you create three separate bibliographic entries. Else, just create 1 entry with 3 separate URL strings, especially as all 3 formulas come from a common manufacturer.

Comment: @Mico Right now, I just have these as footnotes which is good enough. The reviewer claims that it would better to list them as references because the "HTML" would read better. Frankly I could care less about that. I would have to either reference each formula as a separate reference (API style), in which case I would add about 20 references to the text and the reader would lose his place in the text as a result, which text in print or as a pdf just uses the formulas, and wouldn't improve the HTML presentation anyway. You suggestion would not

Comment: con't distinguish between formulas which formulas are which and they need to be one-one with what they are linked to. So, if the answer to my question that it is unusual and no one feels like answering it, then I will just go back to the reviewer and say no, I can't do that.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a clue as to how to set up a two-tiered bibliographic entry type. Maybe somebody else does. Incidentally, I can't imagine that your readers would be better off with a citation call-out of the form `[12a,b,c]` than with either `[12,13,14]` or `[12-14]`.

Comment: A further thought: I think the reviewer is dead-wrong for suggesting to use -- abuse, or misuse, really -- the bibliographic citing scheme in this way. Usually (universally), one cites sources in order to indicate the source of some thought, idea, or inspiration -- and thus also to avoid creating even the impression of plagiarizing the work of others. If I understand your objective (or, rather, the reviewer's objective), implementing his (her?) suggestion would create the misleading impression that wolfram.com is somehow the originator of these formulas. Not good!

Comment: @Mico Actually, the purpose of my footnotes is to show the reader that when I use an identity, that such a thing exists. Turning it into a reference seems inappropriate, but if I did, I would want it as a list. For example, $-\pi \csc (\pi \alpha )=\Gamma (-\alpha ) \Gamma (\alpha +1)=\alpha \Gamma (-\alpha ) \Gamma (\alpha )$ footnote: From http://functions.wolfram.com/06.05.16.0001.01 and http://functions.wolfram.com/06.05.16.0002.01

Comment: @Mico The reviewer is indeed "dead-wrong" but the rules are that (1) the reviewer is always right (2) when the reviewer is dead-wrong see rule (1). Besides that, if I need to do something then it is what it is. Sure, I can sometimes put my foot down, and in this case the reviewer slid me a break, as you can see, [lots of links in the footnotes](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10928-021-09779-4.pdf).